# How to give where condition using for loop in Codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, where-clause

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9055954
    [1] => 2736738
    [2] => 1234
    [3] => 2844725
)
```

I need to a where condition to select the ids form database table add_family whose id is not equal to any one of the value in array, I'm using codeigniter, how can I check it using for loop for where condition.

Comment: could you please give us more details, ex. your code where is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to run a `for` loop to do this. You can simply check it by running a simple query which will select all records from table after excluding `ids` as specified in array:

```
$ignore_ids = [9055954, 2736738, 1234, 2844725];

$this->db->where_not_in('add_family', $ignore_ids);
```